# Can I register as a freelancer in the UK when living abroad?

Tags: uk, registration

I am French and have lived in the UK for the past 4 years. I have just left my job and my house to travel in Europe and Australia and have no fixed address in the UK. As a matter of fact, I don't know at this point if I will come back to the UK at all.

I am wondering if I can use any address in the UK (e.g. a friend's) to register as self-employed? Will it cause them any issues?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Last time I was interested to work with an address in London (I am a French living in France) I found there are some companies which provide you a complete professional physical address even from abroad. It was not expensive and some could even forward your mail and give a phone number with an assistant. 
Even if it is simpler by using a friend I think It will be a more "professional" think and so you don't bother friends for that.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you. I'll start investigate that solution then.